# Recording a video Android

Tags: android, android-studio, amazon-kinesis, screen-recording

Greeting to The reader

Hi, I am working on AWS Kinesis video stream. We have a screen where we are using a container layout which may or may not be full screen and the screen may or may not have other static content. The video is rendered on View of SDK which is an extension of SurfaceView. Now i need to record the video (only video not other content on screen).

I tried some libraries but they failed to render video
Media recorder need persistent surface but the surface view used by SDK is not persistent.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks